# Magento 2.2.6: i want to add form on banner

Tags: magento2.2, forms

I want search form in banner so, how to add form in banner in home page in magento 2.2.6

Comment: Hav you using any module?

Comment: I created one module to modify registration page of customer

Answer (score 0):

Add the bellow code where you want to display the form search:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```